# Rerunning debugging Python with gdb

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a C++ program with gdb. After running `gdb python`, I set the breakpoints and run the program. However, after I quit the program, I leave the gdb debugger altogether.

If I make a change in my code and would like rerun the program, I have to do the whole process again. Run 'gdb python`, type the breakpoints (because the commands are not in the history), etc.

Is there a more efficient way to deal with this debugging problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized `Ctrl +C` does the job @EmployedRussian is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

> I leave the gdb debugger altogether

Why? Don't do that.

Instead, leave GDB running, rebuild your program (in another terminal), then use GDB `run` command again to re-run the rebuilt program.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing the idea,  I wasn't sure how to do it before, `quit` did not work.